# Difference in expected output in regards to composition

Tags: java, inheritance, printing, output, composition

I'm new to programming so I was going through an online lesson (Java Fundamentals part 1, Basic Composition by John Sonmez on Pluralsight. I'm pretty sure you can start a trial because I can't link to the video directly) when I hit a snag. When calling the print(1) method on the *myPrinter* object here, the instructor got the output "Load more paper!" while I continue to get the output "MY PRINTER is On!". I believed I had written the code down exactly like his but obviously I'm missing something. From the logic I've deduced of the code(which is clearly wrong somehow), it *is* supposed to print "MY PRINTER is On!" since the *pages* variable in the **PaperTray** class is 0, which makes the *isEmpty* method in that class return false (because 0>0 is false), a condition that alongside the "copies > 0" condition only allows for the while loop in the *print* method to execute. On the other hand that would go against the logic of the exercise, which was to show that I would be told to load more paper until I ran the *addPaper* method of  the **PaperTray** class, which would make pages = 1, meaning the isEmpty method would then resolve to true and myPrinter.print(1) would appropriately output "Load more paper!" (which it does if i change *pages* to 1 manually!). I went back into intelliJ and coded it exactly as I saw it, down to the coding style but now I've goofed in formatting it here. Am I overlooking something tiny?

```
    public class Main {
              public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Printer myPrinter = new Printer(true, "MY PRINTER");        
                    myPrinter.print(1);  //For the instructor this outputs "Load more paper!" while my output is "MY PRINTER is On!"      
                }     
            }
```

Printer class

```
public class Printer extends Machine{

            private String modelNumber;
            private PaperTray paperTray = new PaperTray(); 

            public Printer(boolean isOn, String modelNumber)
            {
                super(isOn);
                this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
            }
            public void print(int copies)
            {
                String onStatus = ""; 
                if(isOn)
                    onStatus = " is On!";
                else
                    onStatus=" is Off!";
                  //Uses Machine to determine onStatus
                String textToPrint = modelNumber + onStatus;

                while( copies > 0 && !paperTray.isEmpty() ) //while copies > 0 and paperTray.isEmpty() is false
                {
                    System.out.println(textToPrint);  
                    copies--;   true
                }
                if( paperTray.isEmpty() ) // if paperTray.isEmpty is true
                {
                    System.out.println("Load more paper!"); 
                }
            }
```

PaperTray class to simulate paper tray of a printer

```
class PaperTray{
              int pages = 0;
              public void addPaper(int count){
                pages += count;
              }
              public void usePage(){
                pages--;
              }
              public boolean isEmpty(){
                return pages > 0;
              }//Since 0 > 0 is false, only the while loop of the Printer's print method executes! 
            }
```

Machine class to classify the printer

```
class Machine
```

{

```
                protected boolean isOn;

                public Machine(boolean isOn){
                    this.isOn=isOn;
                }
                public void TurnOn(){
                    isOn=true;
                }
                public void TurnOff(){
                    isOn=false;
                }
         } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `isEmpty` of `PaperTray` -- you're testing if it's empty by testing if the number of pages is greater than zero, which is the opposition condition of being empty. The method body should be:

```
return pages == 0;
```

Comment: See that makes sense although I'd put 
    return pages <= 0 
in case of negative numbers, but I'm still wondering why it worked when his method said return pages > 0. Maybe I shouldn't even worry about it